# Docker container has volumes that aren't defined anywhere

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I had a container running from an image, `sebp/lighttpd`, that had a volume mounted on it at `/var/www/localhost`. In my docker-compose file, I changed the config for that service to

```
build:
    context: web/
image: myproject-web
```

Where neither the dockerfile at `web/Dockerfile` nor its `from:` image (`bistenes/lighttpd`) have any volumes defined. I ran `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`, but the new container still has the old volume mounts defined, wiping the data I'm trying to `COPY` into `/var/www/localhost` when the container runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2127), which concludes with "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"

The issue indicates that `docker-compose rm` will do the trick.

I used `docker inspect ${CONTAINER}` to find the volume IDs, did `docker rm ${CONTAINER}`, then `docker volume rm ${VOLUMES}`.